# How to change material button disabled state background color in my theme?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I am using Material design components in my android project.

My promblem is that i cannot change **DISABLED** background color of the material button (https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/).

I want to change **DISABLED** color in my theme, but i cannot figure out how to do this.

I tried looking at `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` style and  I found out that it has `"backgroundTint"` property:

```
<item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector</item>
```

But it does not have disabled state style, see below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

I can always add it myself, but where does initial greyed out color of a **DISABLED** button come from?

What is the best way to change this color globally in my theme?

P.S. I am using `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The color used by disable state is the last line in the selector:

```
<item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
```

[image]
[image]

To change **globally** just use the **`materialButtonStyle`** attribute in your app theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
  <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/My.Button</item>
</style>
```

Then you can customize your style as you prefer.

```
<style name="My.Button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
 <item name="backgroundTint">@color/my_color_selector</item>
 ...
</style>
```

or the new `materialThemeOverlay` attribute to override the colors (it requires the version 1.1.0 of the library):

```
<style name="My.Button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
 <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyButtonThemeOverlay</item>
 ...
</style>

<style name="MyButtonThemeOverlay">
   <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/mycolor</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout just add the Button **without** style. It will use the style defined globally by the `My.Button` style.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
  .../>
```

Comment: This worked while drawable selector didn't work!! but why??

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason (for the colorOnSurface/disabled button color override) :(

Comment: Ooh la la this is nice. I could not see how to just make a button use colorSecondary, and retain it's disabled color without me having to specify a backgroundTint as a selector. I think the best solution is just to use a theme overlay

Answer (score 6):

1.Create folder res/color.
2.Create xml like color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/colorDisabled"  />
    <item android:color="@color/colorEnabled" />
</selector>
```

3.Create a style in **styles.xml** with parent  Widget.MaterialComponents.Button .

```
<style name="MaterialButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/color_states_materialbutton</item>
</style>
```

4.Set style on the MaterialButton in layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/MaterialButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/disabled_material_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="@string/button_label_disabled"/>
```

Comment: this worked for me. Had never used a color folder inside the res folder before. Pretty cool.